# How can i convert datetime to date format in sqlite selected vaues

Tags: sqlite

I just try to convert datetime to date, but without success. Help me to do it:

```
select date('startTime') from usertable ;

select datetime(substr(startTime, 7, 4 )) from usertable;
```

Answer (score 1):

> Just try this.. it will convert datetime to date.

```
SELECT strftime('%d-%m-%Y', fieldname)

SELECT strftime('%d-%m-%Y', 'now') gives output 5-06-2015
```